# How can I list all packages I've installed from a particular repository?

Tags: apt, package-management

How can I list all packages I've installed from a particular repository?

How can I list all installed packages that are not available from the main Ubuntu archives, and also see which repositories they came from?  (If I knew the answer to this question, I could grep that list for a particular PPA name to find out the answer to my first question.)

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be an existing command-line tool for this (sadly), I'll accept one of the GUI answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Expand the "Installed Software" item in Ubuntu Software Center. You'll see a list of all the different repositories that you've enabled. Clicking on the repo will show you the packages you've installed from each.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that option is only available in Ubuntu 10.10 or am I missing something? My Software Center doesn't display sources below that menu.

Comment: In my version I have an "Installed" dropdown at the top. When I select that option, I can choose the various sources (core, for purchse, PPA...)

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, this page is no longer available. However, synaptic has a similar feature -- click "Origin" in the bottom-left.

Answer (score 34):

There seems to be no record of the origin of an *installed* package.

If you are fine with getting the location from whence a package of the
same name would be downloaded from, this is available through
`apt-cache policy`. The following (rather ugly) script does the trick
for me:

```sh
LC_ALL=C dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}:${Status}\n' -W '*' \
  | fgrep ':install ok installed' \
  | cut -d: -f1 \
  | (while read pkg; do 
       inst_version=$(apt-cache policy $pkg \
                                | fgrep Installed: \
                                | awk '{ print $2 }'); 
       origin=$(apt-cache policy "$pkg" \
                          | fgrep " *** ${inst_version}" -C1 \
                          | tail -n 1 \
                          | cut -c12-); 
       echo $pkg $origin; 
     done)
```

Note that it's quite fragile, as it makes assumptions about the output
of `apt-cache policy`, which might change across versions...

Comment: Yeah, this would basically mean writing a tool from scratch.  And I think parsing /var/lib/apt/lists with Perl or Python would be faster and more robust.

Comment: Works normally here, in 2018 :) Thank you!

Comment: I developed a [similar solution](https://blog.famzah.net/2018/04/24/find-the-repository-of-all-installed-packages-on-debian-or-ubuntu/) tested on Ubuntu and Debian.

Answer (score 28):

Open Synaptic Package Manager and click the "Origin" button on the bottom of the left sidebar. It will list your sources. Select a source to see the available/installed packages.

Answer (score 4):

This script lists packages that are installed and available in the PPA:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Give PPA name as an argument, e.g. ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

name1="$(echo "$1"|cut -d: -f2|cut -d/ -f1)"
name2="$(echo "$1"|cut -d/ -f2)"

awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' \
/var/lib/apt/lists/*"$name1"*"$name2"*Packages |
xargs dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Package}\n' 2>/dev/null  | awk '/^[^ ]+ ok installed/{print $4}'
```

I applied [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-list-packages-from-ppa.html).

BTW, as for removing PPA from use, use ppa-purge program; I have created an improved version of it [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~jarnos/ppa-purge/+git/ppa-purge).

Answer (score 3):

Under Quantal (12.10), the space in the origin line needs to be removed.

```
LC_ALL=C dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}:${Status}\n' -W '*' \
 | fgrep ':install ok installed' \
 | cut -d: -f1 \
 | (while read pkg; do 
   inst_version=$(apt-cache policy $pkg \
                            | fgrep Installed: \
                            | cut -d: -f2-); 
   origin=$(apt-cache policy "$pkg" \
                      | fgrep " ***${inst_version}" -C1 \
                      | tail -n 1 \
                      | cut -c12-); 
   echo $pkg $origin; 
 done)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a system without a Wayland/X server (like a Raspberry Pi), the answers of [andrewsomething](https://askubuntu.com/a/6011/1037999) and [lovinglinux](https://askubuntu.com/a/5978/1037999) cannot be used. The answer of [jarno](https://askubuntu.com/a/719232/1037999) limits the use case to PPAs only, although the question is of general interest. The scripts from [Riccardo Murri](https://askubuntu.com/a/6073/1037999) and [Graham Dunn](https://askubuntu.com/a/266932/1037999) are quite slow due to the repeated `apt-cache policy` calls (like about 10 minutes runtime).

So this is my call solving the general case on a shell being a lot faster (like less than 10 seconds runtime)

```
apt list --installed 2> /dev/null \
  | cut -d/ -f1 \
  | parallel -n200 apt-cache policy \
  | rg '^(\S+)[\s\S]+?\* (?:\S+\s+){3}(\S+)' -Uor '$1 $2'
```

`apt list --installed` gets a list of all installed packages ignoring apt's message about possible future format changes with `2> /dev/null` and extracting only the package names with `cut` by using `/` as a delimiter with `-d/` and returning the first field with `-f1`.

Then, `apt-cache policy` is used to get more information about all the packages. This could be executed with xargs, as `apt-cache` expects its input as command line argument. As this is the remaining performance-critical part, GNU `parallel` from package `parallel` is used instead to run multiple `apt-cache` processes in parallel looking up 200 packages with each using `-n200`. Note, that xargs can run multiple commands in parallel, too, but synchronizes output on newline, which is not correct here in general.

Finally, `apt-cache`'s output is parsed with `rg` from package `ripgrep` which is a very fast and multiline capable `grep` successor with `-U` allowing to output two regular expression capture groups with `-or '$1 $2'`. The regular expression captures the package name with `^(\S+)`, skips to the last star marking the installed repository with `[\s\S]+?\*` , then skips three words with `(?:\S+\s+){3}` and finally captures the repository with `(\S+)`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this Python script should find all non-Ubuntu packages installed on your machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# This lists all packages not from Ubuntu's (e.g. main/universe) repositories
# To use, simply download/copy into a .py file and run with:
# python3 list_non_ubuntu.py
#
# If you receive an import error, you may need to install python3-apt first with e.g.
# sudo apt install python3-apt
# but this is often not necessary

import apt


cache = apt.Cache()
package_count = 0

for package in cache:
    if (
        package.is_installed
        and package.candidate.origins[0].origin != "Ubuntu"
    ):
        package_origin = package.candidate.origins[0]
        print(
            package.name,
            # See https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt.package.html#apt.package.Origin
            # for further details on the meanings of the below
            package_origin.origin,  # The Origin, as set in the Release file
            package_origin.archive,  # The archive (eg. Ubuntu release name)
            package_origin.component,  # The component (eg. main/universe)
            package_origin.site,  # The hostname of the site.
            # package_origin.label,  # The Label, as set in the Release file
            # package_origin.trusted,  # Origin trusted (Release file signed by key in apt keyring)
        )
        package_count += 1

print(package_count, "packages not from Ubuntu")
```

On my machine this took under 5 seconds to run, compared to over 8 minutes for the current top answer (from Riccardo/Pablo). Output is in the format:

```
$ python3 list_non_ubuntu.py 
azure-cli azure-cli focal focal main packages.microsoft.com
google-chrome-stable Google LLC stable main dl.google.com
[...]
signal-desktop . xenial xenial main updates.signal.org
8 packages not from Ubuntu
```

You could then add an additional `and package.candidate.origins[0].site == "[ppa-domain.com]"` after the `.origin != "Ubuntu"` if you only want ones from a particular ppa.

Comment: This is neat!  I think you need `python3-apt` rather than `python-apt`.

BTW is there a reason to use `cache[package.name].is_installed` instead of `package.is_installed`?

Comment: Both good suggestions, thanks @MariusGedminas -- I have changed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an `aptitude` solution for the sake of how to use `aptitude search` (which I might probably soon forget how to use :-D), I created a little bash function which you can store into your `~/.bashrc` file :

```shell
function listInstalledPackagesFromRepo {
    local architecture=$(dpkg --print-architecture)
    local repo="${1/ppa:/}"

    aptitude search -F '%p' "?origin(${repo/\//-}\>) ( ?architecture($architecture) | ?architecture(all) ) ?installed"
}
```

This `aptitude` call can even be simplified like this :

```shell
aptitude search -F '%p' "?origin(${repo/\//-}\>) ?installed"
```

And here's an example of how to call this function :

```shell
$ listInstalledPackagesFromRepo ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
albert
libgee2
libgnome-menu2
macbuntu-os-icons-v1804
macbuntu-os-ithemes-v1804
macbuntu-os-plank-theme-v1804
slingscold
```

And finally a much more efficient way to do it :

```shell
$ grep-dctrl -n -sPackage . /var/lib/apt/lists/*${repo/\//_}_*Packages  | xargs dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} is ${Status}\n' 2>/dev/null | awk '/ installed/{print$1}' | sort -u
```

Or if you don't have `grep-dctrl` :

```shell
$ grep -h -P -o "^Package: \K.*" /var/lib/apt/lists/*${repo/\//_}_*Packages | xargs dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} is ${Status}\n' 2>/dev/null | awk '/ installed/{print$1}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Most installed packages (on my machines) come from the default repository for the distro.
The below pipeline (inspired by [Patrick Häcker's answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1331065)) lists packages from *other* repositories.

Outputs installed packages' name and source (url) in two columns, grouped by source. Uses [`rg`/ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).

```bash
dpkg --get-selections \
| grep --extended-regexp $'\tinstall' \
| cut --fields 1 \
| xargs --max-args 100 apt-cache policy \
| rg --multiline --replace $'$1\t$2\n' -- '^(\S+?):(?:.*\n)+?^ \*+.*\n +\d+ (\S+)(?: .*\n)+' \
| grep --invert-match "$(apt-cache policy linux-base | rg --only-matching --replace '$1' -- ' {8}\d+ (\S+)' | head --lines 1)\$" \
| sort --key 2 \
| column --table
```

Example output:

```
cri-tools                    https://apt.kubernetes.io
kubeadm                      https://apt.kubernetes.io
kubectl                      https://apt.kubernetes.io
kubelet                      https://apt.kubernetes.io
kubernetes-cni               https://apt.kubernetes.io
containerd.io                https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
docker-buildx-plugin         https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
docker-ce-cli                https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
docker-ce-rootless-extras    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
docker-ce                    https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
docker-compose-plugin        https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
```