# How to list all the packages which are installed from PPAs?

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa

I installed many packages from many PPAs on my system. I want to list all the installed packages which are installed from launchpad PPAs, not repositories.

Is this possible through command-line?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/43581/how-to-list-packages-from-a-ppa-source-in-command-line

Comment: No.its a different one.

Comment: Not a command line utility, but very useful is the [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager). Lists, installs, and removes packages from PPAs.

Comment: From a given PPA: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-ppa

Answer (score 30):

The following command returns the package name and its ppa (if installed from a ppa):

```
apt-cache policy $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall$ | awk '{ print $1 }') | perl -e '@a = <>; $a=join("", @a); $a =~ s/\n(\S)/\n\n$1/g;  @packages = split("\n\n", $a); foreach $p (@packages) {print "$1: $2\n" if $p =~ /^(.*?):.*?500 http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/(.*?)\s/s}'
```

Details:

- `dpkg --get-selections` gives only the installed packages after `grep -v deinstall$`
- `awk '{ print $1 }'` returns only the package name
- `perl -e '@a = <>; $a=join("", @a)'` concatenates all the lines returned by `apt-cache policy`
- `$a =~ s/\n(\S)/\n\n$1/g;` adds a newline between each package section
- `@packages = split("\n\n", $a);` is a perl array containing all the packages infos, one package per item.
- `foreach $p (@packages) {print "$1: $2\n" if $p =~ /^(.*?):.*?500 http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/(.*?)\s/s}` is a loop where the package and the ppa are printed if a ppa with prio 500 is found in the policy.

Comment: Short answer/code, looong time for execution.

Answer (score 13):

- **`aptitude`** command below shows list of installed packages for active PPA's in `sources.list`.

  ```
  aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ~Oppa)'
  ```

  `~Oppa` means Origin contains 'ppa'

  **Reference:** [aptitude - Search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html)
- In case PPA repository was removed, packages become obsolete. Alternatively use this filter instead `~Oppa | -o` reference:

  [How to get a list of all packages installed from PPAs even for PPA repositories that may have been removed](https://askubuntu.com/a/910896/26246)

Comment: Another Cool Capability of `aptitude`  +1

Comment: @user.dz On my ubuntu, `aptitude` says : `E: Match pattern ends unexpectedly (expected ')').`

Comment: @SebMa , I have just tried it in the online LXD container (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) from https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/try-it/ , it is working fine. Which shell you are using? and please confirm that you are using the same shell string limiters, as in `'string'` .

Comment: @user.dz My mistake, I had an `aptitude` shell function which has a bug. Your command works on my system now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

The source of an installed package can be checked using `apt-cache`, for example

`$ apt-cache policy oracle-java7-installer`

```
oracle-java7-installer:
  Installed: 7u51-0~webupd8~7
  Candidate: 7u51-0~webupd8~7
  Version table:
 *** 7u51-0~webupd8~7 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The output of `apt-cache policy <package_name>` contains the source.

One can use the following script to obtain the list of packages installed from PPAs.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "List of packages which are not installed from Ubuntu repository"
for i in `dpkg -l | grep "^ii" | awk '{print $2}'`
do
    j=`apt-cache policy "$i" | grep "ppa.launchpad.net"` 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$i"
        #echo "$i $j"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It doesn’t work if you selected a different mirror. For instance I have `gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1         500 http://ubuntu.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
`

Comment: In this case `google-chrome-stable` is not installed from a PPA; it  has just a separate repository.

Comment: Ok, I saw that. But you came with a really bad example which can make novice users to think that if a package is not from Ubuntu repositories, then the package is from a PPA. The OP's question is about PPAs.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I got your points and Edited my post. you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Better now, even if there is a problem with the time  for execution which is realy looong.

Answer (score 3):

In accordance with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148968/147044) and [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-list-packages-from-ppa.html), you can get a list of all packages from all the PPAs installed on your system using the following bash code:

```bsh
for APT in $(find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list); do
  grep -o "^deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9\-]\+/[a-z0-9\-]\+" $APT | while read ENTRY ; do
    USER=$(echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f4)
    PPA=$(echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f5)
    awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*$USER*$PPA*Packages
    done
done
```

And in accordance with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17829/147044), you can get a list of all installed packages in your system using:

```bsh
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1
```

Now, let's join these two ideas to get a list of all the packages which are installed from PPAs:

```bsh
(for APT in $(find /etc/apt/ -name \*.list); do
  grep -o "^deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9\-]\+/[a-z0-9\-]\+" $APT | while read ENTRY ; do
    USER=$(echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f4)
    PPA=$(echo $ENTRY | cut -d/ -f5)
    awk '$1 == "Package:" { if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $2; }' /var/lib/apt/lists/*$USER*$PPA*Packages
    done
done; dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | cut -f1) | sort | awk 'dup[$0]++ == 1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Install [synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install-synaptic.html.en). You can then browse packages by "origin" or even any other custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know how many packages I had from each ppa, so I slightly modified Sylvain's awesome answer:

```bsh
apt-cache policy $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall$ | awk '{ print $1 }') \
| perl -e '@a = <>; $a=join("", @a); $a =~ s/\n(\S)/\n\n$1/g;  @packages = split("\n\n", $a); foreach $p (@packages) {printf "%-40s %s\n", $2, $1 if $p =~ /^(.*?):.*?500 http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/(.*?)\s/s}' \
| sort \
| uniq -c -w 40
```

by printing ppa first and using only first 40 characters to count & deduplicate with `uniq`, I can get this kind of output:

```
  5 alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu               flatpak
147 bleedingedge/focal-bleed/ubuntu          bzip2
  1 justinabrahms/ttf-cascadia-code/ubuntu   ttf-cascadia-code
 44 libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu                   fonts-opensymbol
 71 savoury1/backports/ubuntu                bash
 41 savoury1/multimedia/ubuntu               dav1d
  8 strukturag/libheif/ubuntu                aom-tools
 12 ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu      gdal-bin
```