# PPA spring cleaning --- list packages installed from a PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa

This is a Q&A-style thing --- hoping to help you in this period of new LTS release(s). There are a lot of links in this post, follow them and upvote them to give the authors the relevant kudos.

It is often suggested to [remove or purge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309966/difference-between-ppa-purge-and-add-apt-repository-r) all of your PPAs when doing a version upgrade; I often have a lot of troubles remembering which PPA are installed and which packages are "owned" by a particular PPA --- you sometime install a PPA but that does not mean that you have installed all packages from it.

For the list of PPA there are [quite a lot of good scripts around](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148932/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-repositories-and-ppas-from-the-command-line); and for [discovering the packages really installed from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-ppa) you can use `apt-cache policy` or similar commands.

But --- what about a one-stop script to list all your installed PPAs and all the packages you have installed from them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/447129/how-to-list-all-the-packages-which-are-installed-from-ppas

Answer (score 4):

The following script will give you a list like the following:

```
PPA:tualatrix/ppa
--->  ubuntu-tweak
PPA:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
--->  gimp
--->  gimp-data
--->  gimp-help-common
--->  gimp-help-en
--->  gimp-help-en-gb
--->  gimp-help-es
--->  gimp-help-it
--->  gimp-plugin-registry
--->  libgimp2.0
--->  libopenjpeg-dev
--->  libopenjpeg5
```

Script following (copy it to a file and make it executable):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
list_all_packages_repos() {
apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | awk 'NR >= 6 { print $2 }') |
  awk '/^[^ ]/    { split($1, a, ":"); pkg = a[1] }
    nextline == 1 { nextline = 0; printf("%-40s %-50s %s\n", pkg, $2, $3) }
    /\*\*\*/      { nextline = 1 }'
    }

list_packages_of() { #1 is the tmpfile, $2 is the ppa regexp
    grep "$2" "$1" | awk '{print "---> ", $1}'
}

# cache all packages files now 

tmpfile=/tmp/list_pcks.$$.txt
list_all_packages_repos > $tmpfile

# listppa Script to get all the PPA installed on a system ready to share for reininstall
for APT in $(find /etc/apt/ -name "*.list"); do
    grep -o "^deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/[a-z0-9\-]\+/[a-z0-9\-]\+" "$APT" | while read ENTRY ; do
        USER=$(echo "$ENTRY" | cut -d/ -f4)
        PPA=$(echo "$ENTRY" | cut -d/ -f5)
        echo  PPA:$USER/$PPA
    list_packages_of "$tmpfile" "$USER/$PPA"
    done
done

rm "$tmpfile"
```