# Problems with apt-get ppa from launch pad

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad

I'm running Ubuntu Server

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS  
Release: 14.04  
Codename: trusty
```

And when I run apt-get update is get the following errors

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404 Not Found  
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/inizan-yannick/mono/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not found  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do to resolve this, so I can once again run updates for my server, sorry if this is a simple answer, but I'm new to Linux package management.
Thanks

Comment: @mchid As far as I know, this is a stock Ubuntu server running on AWS, I have not added or removed any packages that come by default from AWS.  I wasn't necessarily accessing any particular package, just updating all that needed it.

Comment: okay, then follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Comment: @mchid so just remove it by commenting out that PPA? I just don't want to remove a package that I may need.

Comment: @Greyhammer what do you want to install/use from that ppa ?

Comment: @Ravan I'm assuming that the package came from AWS, as this server is basically stock Ubuntu Image from them. I've never installed any packages from that PPA that i know of.  Nor do i know how it got into my source list.  (I inherited the server from someone else)

Comment: yes, commenting out the ppa will not remove any packages, this is safe to do and will fix the problem. It may be listed in your /etc/apt/sources.list file or there may be an individual file for this ppa in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory if it is not listed there

Comment: Is there a way to figure out if any software currently installed on this server relies on that PPA?

Comment: @Greyhammer this doesn't answer that question directly but it doesn't matter because this ppa doesn't exist. If any newer version of that software is released by ubuntu you will receive an update. Other than that, you won't receive any future updates for whatever package it may be from that ppa. As far as functionality is concerned, if it works now, you are fine. Worst case scenario would be some security flaw that is not patched.

Comment: this will show you how to list those packages http://askubuntu.com/questions/447129/how-to-list-all-the-packages-which-are-installed-from-ppas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the advise of mchid, and commented out the package that was in the  /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory for that failing package.

Now the server updates fully.