# How to get a list of all packages installed from PPAs even for PPA repositories that may have been removed

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

I've already seen this question:

[How to list all the packages which are installed from PPAs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447129/how-to-list-all-the-packages-which-are-installed-from-ppas)

It only works for packages installed from PPAs where the PPA repository is still added to the system.

Is there a way to get the same kind of list but including all packages from all PPA repositories that are current added or have been added in the past?

Answer (score 5):

You may search for installed obsolete packages, either locally installed or their source repository is disabled)

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ~o)'
```

Also if you want both obsolete + ppa ones:

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, ~Oppa | ~o)'
```

**Reference:** [aptitude - Search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html)

Answer (score 1):

PPAs that were configured as software source in the past but got removed are not logged anywhere. You can't find out what PPAs have been added once.

You can only remember those yourself and look their content list up online at https://launchpad.net.