# Unable to locate package mesa?

Tags: drivers, mesa

Following [this guideline](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

then,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt-get install mesa
```

The last results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesa
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Perhaps there are other packages available from that PPA. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/43581/how-to-list-packages-from-a-ppa-source-in-command-line?s=1|1.3466 on how to list the packages in a PPA.

Answer (score 0):

mesa is a source, not a package. Read the ppa page before using or **even adding to your sources** - [https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Exorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

In particular -

> This PPA is currently meant to be used as a whole. Please do *not* individually install packages from it, add it to your sources and let your package manager pull in every update

It's also possible that as far as 14.04 the ppa can only be used with an install from 14.04/14.04.1 images. 14.04.2 & 14.04.3 may not be suitable candidates for that ppa.