# Ubuntu 14.04 Software Center Install From PPA

Tags: software-center, ppa

I have installed a PPA. Now I want to view all software that the PPA has to offer in the Ubuntu Software Center GUI. Everywhere I look on the internet they say,"The packages available from the PPA can be seen by expanding the Get Software menu in Software Center's left column." I don't have a "Get Software" menu. What I see in the left column is: "Accessories, Books and Magazines, Developers Tools, ...". So how do I get the column with the entries, "Get Software, Installed Software, History", where Get Software has a pulldown where I can select my PPA? I can currently only see "Provided by Ubuntu" and "Canonical Partners". When I go to Edit->Software Sources->Other Software I can see several of my added PPA sources with check marks, but I cannot see them in the main menu.

I already know how to install the application from the command line. I am trying to find out why, after installing a PPA in terminal, I don't have the ability to see the enabled repositories in the left panel.

I want to see this:

[image: Software Center Filter By Repository]

All I see is this:
[image: Software Center Left Panel]

and...

[image: Software Center Available Sources]

[image: Software Center Added PPA]

So I have clearly added some PPAs, so now how do I get USC to show them in the main window? If you go to the link:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

it magically goes from one view to the other, but skips the details on how to get there. I see a lot of similar questions which keep getting marked as "duplicate" and refer to that link. Maybe some more clarification is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list packages from a ppa/source in command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43581/how-to-list-packages-from-a-ppa-source-in-command-line)

Comment: @Serg: Thanks for your link. I would like to be able to do this from the command line as well as from USC. I could do the whole thing from the command line, but I am trying to get a better rounded knowledge of how to use Ubuntu. BTW please see my new edits so you will have a better understanding of my problem.

Comment: It shows my enabled & installed from ppas here but seems pretty much clueless as to what's in the ppas & what I've installed from those ppas. Far better to use synaptic package manager > Origin. It will give you 2 entries for ppas you've installed from, a now for installed & below that all packages in that ppa. SC is not good for such stuff & Never will be.