# How do I find additional free repositories for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: package-management, software-center, repository

I'm new to Linux. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I want to find additional open source free software packages available for installation.  I tried to add other software sources to the Ubuntu Software applications but after a lengthy process of updating the available applications by downloading updates, the new software repositories don't show and I have the exact same packages available as I always had. I used a repository list generator website to find the URL for the repositories to add.

Obviously I'm doing something stupid? I don't think I yet fully understand how repositories work despite much reading about it. Is it like having multiple Windows Stores? Or multiple Android Google Plays???

Thanks in advance for any help at all which would be greatly appreciated.

johnnym

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and [How to search for an official PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503201/how-to-search-for-an-official-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Xubuntu you can install software from repositories but it's not the only place that you can achieve free open software. You can search at google the program that you want and you can find a lot of alternatives in Ubuntu Systems. For example, you can install skype for Ubuntu Systems in their official page, and you can find beta versions programs for linux too, then I encourage you to ask here if you dont find the software that you wanna install on your Ubuntu :)!

If you wanna list all your availables packages via terminal:

[How to list packages from a ppa/source in command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43581/how-to-list-packages-from-a-ppa-source-in-command-line)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Just to be more specific, I want to find software repositories where I can browse what is available. I do not have any specific packages in mind, I want to see what is available then decide if I want to install.

Comment: You can search the application "software" at your menu (the blue rat) and I think that app shows you all software from your repositories more visual way if you are new ubuntu user. If you need search alternatives repositories and add them to later see your all software, but if you wanna do it via terminal, this command show you all availables packages to install:   
$ sudo dpkg --list