# What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?

Tags: package-management, repository

I'm trying to install programs/files from the getdeb repo but get a "check your internet connection" error.  Programs than I've tried include Qbittorrent and Mozilla-Plugin-VLC.

Through the terminal I get the following errors:

```
Err http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ natty-getdeb/apps qbittorrent amd64 2.8.2-1~getdeb2
  Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/q/qbittorrent/qbittorrent_2.8.2-1~getdeb2_amd64.deb: Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
```

&

```
Err http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ natty-getdeb/apps mozilla-plugin-vlc amd64 1.1.10-1~getdeb1
  Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/v/vlc/mozilla-plugin-vlc_1.1.10-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb: Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (209.105.191.78). - connect (113: No route to host)
```

I'm not having any problems adding/removing other programs/files from my machine.  Is there a problem with GETDEB repo (and if so, is there any way to fix it on my end) or is there something wrong with my computer's configuration?

Answer (score 19):

#### 2019: down again (probably forever)

The former getdeb project page is no longer related to the getdeb repository. With the expiration of their [Google+ account](https://plus.google.com/+getdeb/posts) in 2019 there are inidcators that GetDeb finally ceased to exist.

#### 2013: GetDeb did not exist for some time

Unfortunately due to a power failure with complete data loss both, the GetDeb and the PlayDeb projects were discontinued.

> After the server crash where also the GetDeb and PlayDeb database was lost and given the fact that GetDeb and PlayDeb now have too many packages to be handled as a one-man-project I decided to discontinue GetDeb and PlayDeb. <sup>[GetDeb.net on Google+ 18 Jan 2013](https://plus.google.com/+getdeb/posts)</sup>

#### It could be temporarily restored in 2013

Recently the getdeb and playdeb repositories were re-enabled from a backup and should operate as before.

> Fortunately, we did have an up-to-date backup of the old server at the end. The last days I was busy to get everything set up. The sites are up again and you should be able to browse the packages (none should be lost) as well as to use the repository as usual.
> <sup>[GetDeb.net on Google+ 03 Feb 2013](https://plus.google.com/110683567928974511220/posts/Cmp8EyQsBxw)</sup>

#### What if I still have issues, or if it is down again

Due to server issues or lack of support the repositories may be down again for some time. Then we should disable their repository and wait patiently until they may operate again. Watch out for news on their projekt page or in posts from [getdeb in Google+](https://plus.google.com/+getdeb/posts).

Comment: I need to **purge** Getdeb, but before, **how to check** if there are some dependencies?

Comment: @PeterKrauss Getdeb was to my knowledge not very active recently. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/5976/how-can-i-list-all-packages-ive-installed-from-a-particular-repository to find out what you had installed from them. See if you can get those packages updated from another source, or purge them to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Melebius: thanks a lot for the notice. I updated the answer and removed the now useless link to the former project page.

Answer (score 13):

PlayDeb does have a mirror which you can add to your *software sources*.

I've used this solution when the main *getdeb* repositories go offline for an extended period.

As with all mirrors - do not have both the mirror and the actual site active - tick either but not both.

### How-to

Add the following software sources:

```
deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu lucid-getdeb apps
deb-src http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu lucid-getdeb apps
```

then get the software source key by copying and pasting the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A8A515F046D7E7CF
sudo apt-get update
```

N.B.

1. Change `lucid-getdeb` for you your distro name, `maverick-getdeb`, `natty-getdeb`, `oneiric-getdeb`, `precise-getdeb`, `quantal-getdeb`
2. You can also use the games mirror repo by adding the same two lines, only changing `apps` to `games`

[source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/getdeb-mirror-site.html)

Comment: Thank you! 
For  now getdeb.net is down for three or more days. 
So I changed 
`deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps`
 to 
`deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list` on my Ubuntu Xenial.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you've added a third party apt repository to your sources list, and the server is not available.

The only immediate way to "fix" it for you locally, is to remove that repository from your apt sources list, then run `apt-get update` again, and it should be gone.

If you think you really need to use that repository, then you need to contact whoever maintains it, and discuss its inaccessibility with them.