# "Unable to connect" to getdeb.net, how do I fix it?

Tags: apt, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down)

I want to know what this error means and how to fix it?

The following is the output on the terminal-

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/Release.gpg      Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/apps/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
 W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/precise-getdeb/apps/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to archive.getdeb.net:http:
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```