# Does the update manager handle updates for third party applications?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I have quite a few third party apps, and I was wondering if as long as my computer sees the repository, will it update from update manager? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes it does** provided we had added the third party repository to our sources, and updates are made available from there.

From the *"Settings..."* menu in Update Manager we can define how often we need it to check for updates available. Make sure to not choose *"Never"* to get notified if any newer versions are available for your release.

[image]

By doing so we get regular updates, e.g. for Virtual Box, or applications loaded from the [Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/), or the [getdeb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down) repositories. In case a third party repository is down or we do not want an update notification we may temporarily disable this repository by unticking it in the *"Other Software"* tab.