# is there a reason the Getdeb Repo is always down

Tags: apt, repository

Lately, when I update, the process sticks on get deb:

> *[Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (144.76.200.19)]*

The site - http://getdeb.net/ - times out and the cloudflare message is in no way helpful.

Does anyone know why this repo and site are down? or perhaps anything else about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down)

Answer (score 1):

[Down For Everyone Or Just Me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://getdeb.net/) website reports that the http://getdeb.net/ website is down for everyone. There may be an archive that contains the a .deb file for the package that you want to install or if not you can search for the source code of the package in GitHub and compile it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my inquiry doesn't concern a specific package or program .

I have a decade on Linux, I'm good for instructions on how/where - but thank you for the offer.

I'm wondering about getdeb specifically and, further to that, why it's being included as a repo if it's always down - I've seen it down a number of times in the past few months - it's lacking reliability.

Comment: @SedAwk GetDeb is not included by default in any official Ubuntu flavor.