# Err:39 + getdeb while upgrading and updating

Tags: apt

I get this problem when doing `sudo apt-get update && upgrade` on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
Err:39 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease
Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (144.76.200.19), connection timed outFetched 4,750 kB in 2min 0s (39.5 kB/s)
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease Could not connect to archive.getdeb.net:80 (144.76.200.19), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: looks like a mirror is temporarily down.... try sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing .... and/or try again later

Comment: Possibly related: [What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down)

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaBesneatte it seems that upgrading is working with that but still having issue on updating especially on : 0% [Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (144.76.200.19)].

Comment: looks like adding a mirror per steeldriver comment should fix it