# How to install screenlets on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, screenlets

I want to install Screenlets and I tried the following bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo dpkg -l python-wnck >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "Install python-wnck"
  sudo apt -y install libwnck22
  wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
  sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
fi
sudo dpkg -l python-gnomekeyring >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "OK"
else
  echo "Install python-gnomekeyring"
  wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
  sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
fi
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo sed -i 's/bionic/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

But all I get is this:

```
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ #!/bin/bash
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg -l python-wnck >/dev/null 2>&1
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ if [ $? == 0 ]; then
>   echo "OK"
> else
>   echo "Install python-wnck"
>   sudo apt -y install libwnck22
>   wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
>   sudo dpkg -i python-wnck_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
>   sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
> fi
OK
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg -l python-gnomekeyring >/dev/null 2>&1
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ if [ $? == 0 ]; then
>   echo "OK"
> else
>   echo "Install python-gnomekeyring"
>   wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
>   sudo dpkg -i python-gnomekeyring_2.32.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
>   sudo apt --fix-broken -y install
> fi
OK
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: No such file or directory
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo sed -i 's/bionic/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screenlets-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list: No such file or directory
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
Get:1 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                                                                             
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                                 
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                 
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                      
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                                                            
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                        
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found                  
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/inameiname/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
tobi@tobi-System-Product-Name:~$
```

I think sudo apt-get update doesn't work for me, but I don't know how I can fix this.

---

output of `apt-cache policy python3-software-properties`:

```
python3-software-properties:
  Installed: 0.96.24.32.4
  Candidate: 0.96.24.32.4
  Version table:
 *** 0.96.24.32.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.96.20.7 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     0.96.20 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add-apt-repository` command is located in [`software-properties-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=add-apt-repository&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any). You need to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Then you may want to remove or edit paths for problematic PPAs:

1. GetDeb.net is often down. You should follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/51717/66509) and edit corresponding sources.list.
2. The [`inameiname/stable` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~inameiname/+archive/ubuntu/stable)  does not have files for Bionic (but have for Xenial). You should edit its sources.list and change *bionic* to *xenial*.

Then you will be able to update package lists and retry your procedure.

As the result you will get ScreenLets installed and can configure them with `screenlets`:

[image: ScreenLets Manager]

---

Note: for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS one can use official PPA - [`ppa:screenlets/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~screenlets/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial).

Comment: I'm getting this error: E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Then please add output of `apt-cache policy python3-software-properties` to the question.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: Install normal version with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-software-properties=0.96.20.7`.

Comment: E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. (same error again)

Comment: Try to download and install it manually: `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.96.20.7_all.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./python3-software-properties_0.96.20.7_all.deb` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: At the 2nd command I got this errror: __dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--install):
 installed python3-software-properties package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-software-properties__

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: when doing the first, I got several errors which look like this: __dpkg: error processing package apturl-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured__

Comment: at the second and third: __E: The package apturl-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.__

Comment: It seems that you have serious breakage of your system. It is fixable, but you need to do many things by hand.

Comment: I actually install ubuntu just some weeks ago...

Comment: the problem is that I can't install about 60% of all linux applications because of this error

Comment: Try `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apturl/apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb` followed by `sudo dpkg -i --force-all apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: errors at second command: `dpkg: error processing archive apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb (--install):
 installed apturl-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apturl-common.postinst: 27: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apturl-common.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed apturl-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apturl-common_0.5.2ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: for ubuntu 18.04/20.04 https://www.maravento.com/2018/05/screenlets-en-bionic.html

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to follow the guide above. But with this video-tutorial I was able to do it. It is in spanish, and I don't speak Spanish (not a word), yet it is easy to follow what he type into terminal etc.

Como personalizar Ubuntu 18.04 LTS con Screenlets - Parte 3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMXSZ7tVkyM

Comment: fail, for me still need more deeper dependencies package.. 
:'(