# Screenlets throws an error related to python2.7 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04

Tags: screenlets

I've installed screenlets on my system and included:

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all
```

The Screenlet Manager comes up with many screenlet choices but when I try to kickoff any specific app I get this:

```
usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/screenlets/backend.py:166:
Warning: Source ID 63 was not found when attempting to remove it
  gobject.source_remove(self.__timeout)
```

and this continues with Source ID 64, 65,etc...and the app never launches.

There must be some python problem...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install screenlets on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089689/how-to-install-screenlets-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: not a duplicate as far as I can tell...