# ubuntu 16.04 + adapta theme install question

Tags: 16.04, themes, ppa

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to install Adapta dark theme, I'm not that familiar with Linux, so please bear with me.
I tried to follow the instructions on this page [Guide To Install Adapta GTK Theme on Ubuntu](https://omgfoss.com/install-adapta-gtk-theme-ubuntu/), but it did not work, I got the following output from terminal after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt install adapta-gtk-theme`:

```
Hit:1 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease           
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:4 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:5 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease         
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:7 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease          
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                    
Hit:9 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                     
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mikhailnov/pulseeffects/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                           
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-xenial InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/sigil/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vincent-c/wesnoth/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
40 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package adapta-gtk-theme
```

Did I miss some steps? I already have Unity Tweak Tool installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down)

Comment: Thanks N0rbert for helping me to solve the GETDEB error.

Comment: Never mind, I did manage to install it by unpacking a compressed file, the adapta package never worked for me.

Comment: How do I close this question?