# I am having this issue while running 'sudo apt-get update', "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed or opened."

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

```
W: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_xenial-getdeb_apps_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Suggestions that I have tried are:

1. Remove files from an apt directory:

   ```
   sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Changing the server from Ubuntu Software, but I keep receiving an error telling me to contact the administrator

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? You tried to install the get-deb repo but for 16.04 that is no longer supported. Remove that repo and install the one for your version of Ubuntu. Also, it seems get-deb is down right now, this could be the issue too. http://www.getdeb.net/

Comment: I am currently using 16.04. Can you please guide me that how to find the corresponding repo for my version and install it ?

Comment: The versions match so that is likely not the problem. Unfortunately, 16.04 is no longer supported here and end of life. The best advice is to upgrade to a supported release: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Sure will upgrade it, just wanted to solve it for now and matigo answer below worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when the GETDEB repository is down?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51692/what-should-i-do-when-the-getdeb-repository-is-down)

Comment: @karel I have already tried that but it's not working for me

Comment: @N0rbert Are you sure that changing the link for get-deb won't cause any other issues ?

Comment: @N0rbert it's giving me this error 'Failed to fetch http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.225.254.116 80]'

I have even checked the mirror link in other software tab just like this answer suggested

Comment: getdeb seems to be dead, disable this software source.

Comment: Thanks, already did that and it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source file that references the Xenial repository will need to be edited. You can find it via the command line like this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Go to the `apt` directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/apt
   ```
2. Identify the file referencing the bad repository via `grep`:

   ```
   grep -r xenial *
   ```
3. Using `sudo`, edit the file that is mentioned in the output with your preferred text editor, commenting out (or removing) the line. You can comment-out the line by putting a `#` at the front.
4. Save the file and exit.
5. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Comment: Found two files in sources.list.d in which archive.getdeb.net was being used 
1- getdeb.list.save
2- getdeb.list

These files had the same line written in them "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps"

I have commented out both and it's working fine now. Just wanted to make sure if commenting these lines won't cause any other problem

Comment: There should be no problems as a result of commenting out the lines, no. If you do think that there is a problem, you can always *un*comment the lines later 

Comment: Thank you, This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GetDeb)

> GetDeb was an Ubuntu software portal providing legacy versions of software included in Old LTS Ubuntu versions, and software that is omitted from the official repositories.[1] PlayDeb was a sister project with an explicit focus on games. The names come from the .deb package format used by Ubuntu. GetDeb and PlayDeb services can also be used by Ubuntu derivatives starting with 16.04 as the 14.04 packages were removed once when Ubuntu 14.04 reached EOL. Both websites have been redirected to a spam site, and should no longer be trusted.

Getdeb and Playdeb are no longer functional or trusted, and should be removed from software sources ASAP.

Comment: I am getting exact message on 16.04LTS. If Getdeb is not trusted anymore, where can we get the files from?

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever, I have just removed the link to Getdeb in Software & Updates/Preference, all good now.

Comment: What files do you need and for which release?

Comment: I use the graphical interface, "Software & Updates", select "Other Softwatre" tab, uncheck the the option for that contains getdeb.net. I am running version 16.04LTS, mainly for legacy software.