# Switch from elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki to plain old xubuntu without formatting

Tags: xubuntu

In my work computer I originally installed xubuntu 16.04 but started to blindly install stuff to change to dark background themes and I guess at some point I switched from xubuntu to elementary(about a year ago) and now I need to switch back to xubuntu without having to reinstall.

This is because with loki I can't upgrade to 18.04 or even install stuff like mysql-server that now I need for a project.

```
cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID="elementary"
DISTRIB_RELEASE=0.4.1
DISTRIB_CODENAME=loki
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki"
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="0.4.1 Loki"
ID="elementary"
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki"
VERSION_ID="0.4.1"
HOME_URL="http://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://elementary.io/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/"
VERSION_CODENAME=loki
UBUNTU_CODENAME=loki
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I'd install using the standard ISO using the 'something else' option, selecting your partitions and ensuring your 'format' boxes are NOT ticked.  This will install without format, but does erase all system directories. At the end of the installation, it tries to install all programs that you originally had (if in repositories).  My 2c suggestion.  (*edit:  backup your data of course first !!*)

Comment: I agree with guiverc, except that I do not think your custom programs are automatically installed. I think you will need to reinstall this yourself. However, all your custom user settings for these application will still be in effect because these remain preserved in your home folder.

Comment: It would be very difficult like [converting Mint to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058602/66509). You will need to determine elementary's repositories in sources.list then remove such packages and install Ubuntu's packages instead. But at first **backup all your data**.