# Orphaned Package Removal

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

After running GtkOrphan it provides a list of 8 packages suggested for removal.

[image]

Are there likely to be any undesirable consequences in removing any of these using the tools provided within the utility?

Output from running `dpkg -l | grep ^rc`:

```
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic                 4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-modules-4.18.0-15-generic               4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic         4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Running `aptitude` from the terminal with no parameters produces:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tested GtkOrphan on my system.  And it seems that GtkOrphan is dumber than 
`apt-get autoremove -s` or `aptitude search '?obsolete'` (see [help page](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) for full syntax)

On my system I see that only 1 package out of 18 is correctly marked as orphan by GtkOrphan.

As far I can understand the real obsolete or locally installed package do not have any http/https/ftp link in `apt-cache policy ...` output. It should have only `/var/lib/dpkg/status` in the version table.

So we can filter output of `deborphan` by using some scripting (modified version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058602/66509)):

```
cat > find_orphan.sh << \EOF
LC_ALL=C dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}:${Status}\n' -W $@ | \
fgrep ':install ok installed' | cut -d: -f1 | \
(while read pkg; do inst_version=$(apt-cache policy $pkg \
| fgrep Installed: \
| awk '{ print $2 }'); origin=$(apt-cache policy "$pkg" \
| fgrep " *** ${inst_version}" -C1 \
| tail -n 1 \
| cut -c12-); echo $pkg $origin; done)
EOF

sh find_orphan.sh $(deborphan) | grep "/var/lib/dpkg/status" | awk '{print $1}'
```

or do not use GtkOrphan at all and rely on Aptitude with its *Obsolete and Locally Created Packages*

> [image: aptitude orphaned]

or `aptitude search '?obsolete'`:

> ```
> i   rstudio                         - RStudio
> ```

---

The related bug may be the following - [bug 1820906](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deborphan/+bug/1820906).

Comment: in terminal using: sudo aptitude does not indicate any --\ Obsolete Packages and aptitude search '?obsolete' : neither so I guess from your answer, it is best to leave matters well alone.

Comment: So it seems that deborphan is a bit buggy :) There is no need to remove any packages.

Comment: Very much appreciated and an ideal candidate to keep for reference.