# Accidentally copied files to wrong directory

Tags: command-line, sudo, find, rm

Years ago I copied all the files from `/usr/local/bin` into `/bin`.

Now my `/bin` directory is littered with unneeded files. How do I remove them using the `find` command without having to install third party packages?

**Note:** Answers involving third party packages may be helpful to others who have the same question.

Comment: I would search by changed timestamp

Comment: `cp /usr/local/bin /bin` shouldn't copy any files. It should print the error message `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/usr/local/bin'`. Are you sure that's the command you ran?

Comment: @EliahKagan It was in 2017 the command was run by accident and I don't remember doing it. I will revise the question with the question with `-r` flag.

Comment: `cp -r /usr/local/bin /bin` places all copied files in `/bin/bin`, which is very easy to fix. Are you sure *that's* the command you ran? One of my concerns is that people who have run the command(s) mentioned in this question (or variations on them) may find this question by searching, wrongly assume they have a complicated problem, and attempt to follow advice in answers here that is inappropriate for their use case and that, especially if followed wrongly, would turn a problem that is easy to fix (or a total non-problem) into a problem that is hard or impossible to fix.

Comment: @EliahKagan I see your point. Fact is I don't know how the files were copied so I've removed the `cp` command altogether.

Comment: @EliahKagan A **Closer Voter** says this needs more clarity. Do you have any what might be unclear?

Comment: No, I don't see a reason to close this (as unclear or otherwise). I suppose it might be improved by some more information, such as about how many files were in `/usr/local/bin` and what they were from (since that directory is empty by default), and an example of a command that would produce the same effect as what happened even if is not the same command (this wouldn't be either of the commands suggested so far, though--perhaps it would involve a glob). But I really don't think such information is actually *needed* to support the current answers or facilitate further answers.

Comment: @EliahKagan There were 75 files and 8 subdirectories for a total of 83 deletions. They date back to 2017 and I was very surprised to see them there myself. But the same situation would exist for other people if `/home/$USER/Documents` was copied into `/home/admin/Documents`. So the fact it was `/bin` is a relatively mute point although it did open the doors for an answer based upon `dpkg -S`. Thanks for your input I won't worry about the close vote anymore.

Answer (score 8):

### Piece together solutions available in Stack Exchange.

If you do enough research you will find a solution by combining these five answers:

- [How do I compare file names in two directories in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28229014/6929343)
- [How can I remove the first line of a text file using bash/sed script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339941/6929343)
- [Command to prepend string to each line?](https://serverfault.com/a/72749/385348)
- [giving grep output to rm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9601/200094)
- [How do I make rm not give an error if a file doesn't exist?](https://superuser.com/a/76068/662962)

### Trial Run

First run the command without `rm` (remove) option to ensure correct files are being found:

```bash
$ find /usr/local/bin/ /bin/ -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "/bin/" $0}'

/bin/.auto-brightness-config
/bin/auto-brightness-config
/bin/bell
/bin/bell/bell-select-menu
    ( ... OUTPUT SHORTENED ... )
```

### How it works

`find` returns the filenames in Directory 1 (`/usr/local/bin`) followed by Directory 2 (`/bin`(:

#### Directory 1 Files in no particular order

- bbbbb
- aaaaa
- yyyyy

#### Directory 2 Files in no particular order

- echo
- aaaaa
- zcat
- bbbbb
- egrep
- yyyyy

`sort` sorts the two directories' filenames alphabetically

- aaaaa
- aaaaa
- bbbbb
- bbbbb
- echo
- egrep
- yyyyy
- yyyyy
- zcat

`uniq -d` reports only the duplicates

- aaaaa
- bbbbb
- yyyyy

This gives us a list of Directory 1 filenames that were accidentally copied into Directory 2. But there is a blank line at the top of the list.

`tail -n +2` removed the blank line at the top of the list.

`awk '{print "/bin/" $0}'` prepends `/bin/` to each filename so we have:

- /bin/aaaaa
- /bin/bbbbb
- /bin/yyyyy

### Append the `rm` command to pipeline

Now that we've confirmed output is correct append the `rm` command via `xargs`. Note if you have filenames with special characters read the fourth link above for exceptional handling.

```bash
$ find /usr/local/bin/ /bin/ -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "/bin/" $0}' | xargs rm -f
rm: cannot remove '/bin/.auto-brightness-config': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/bin/auto-brightness-config': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/bin/bell': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/bell/bell-select-menu': Permission denied
```

The `Permission denied` error appears because we must use `sudo` powers to run the command. Note the error `'/bin/bell' is a directory`.  Later we will have to manually removed the directory with `rm -d` command.

### `sudo` powers required for `/bin` directory.

The reason permission denied errors occurred is because `root` owns the files in `/bin` we want to delete and our regular user ID isn't allowed to delete them.

Note depending on how you copied the files into the target directory you may not need need `sudo` powers to delete them. For example if you are defined as the owner of the files in the target directory.

Now lets run command with `sudo` powers:

```bash
$ find /usr/local/bin/ /bin/ -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "/bin/" $0}' | sudo xargs rm -f
rm: cannot remove '/bin/bell': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/bell/sounds': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/startup-scripts': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/zap': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/zap/Assembly-Intro-hello': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/zap/Assembly-Intro-hello/BeOS': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/zap/Assembly-Intro-hello/FreeBSD': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '/bin/zap/Assembly-Intro-hello/Linux': Is a directory
```

75 files have been deleted but 8 empty sub-directories are left to remove. We use the `-r` recursive option with `rm` command to delete them:

```bash
$ find /usr/local/bin/ /bin/ -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -d | tail -n +2 | awk '{print "/bin/" $0}' | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Nothing is reported so no more errors!

### Summary

The objective of this answer is to not only solve the problem at hand but show the reader how a problem can be solved by checking multiple existing answers in Stack Exchange.

Comment: -1 because you don't explain what you are actually doing, especially how you determine which files are unneeded.

Comment: @danzel I expanded the answer with explanations of `find`, `sort`, `uniq`, `tail` and `awk` commands.

Answer (score 4):

Your [method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255496/66509) is great, but looks too long.

While [transforming](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058602/66509) Linux Mint to Ubuntu I have used the command like:

```
sudo find /bin -type f -exec dpkg -S {} \; 2> ~/Desktop/not-in-apt.out
```

and as the result for your case we will get wrong copied files list in `~/Desktop/not-in-apt.out`.

You can then review the file and remove files listed in it. Or use some scripting for removal.

To be completely sure that all remaining files in `/bin` are normal you can reinstall them by combining `dpkg -S /bin` with `apt-get install --reinstall` with something like

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /bin | sed 's|: /bin||' | sed 's/,//g')
```

Comment: This is uncanny because what led me to the Q&A is something is zero'ing out `/bin/echo` which breaks `xarg` command which breaks `screenfetch` command. I had to use `dpkg -S /bin/echo` to find out I needed to use `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`.

Comment: Edited to add `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ...` part.

Comment: I really like that you're using `dpkg -S` instead of relying on timestamps. Note that this technique is available for rpm or pacman-based distros, too. Search for `dpkg -S` in [this listing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta#Querying_specific_packages) to find the translation to your distro.