# Packages still present but PPAs removed!

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, uninstall, ppa

I upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 recently.

By default, only official PPAs were enabled so I removed all other PPAs from  "Other Software" tab of "Softwares & Updates"

But all the apps/packages still present. That means probably I won't be able to get community updates now.

Is there any mass uninstaller, to uninstall all apps without any PPA listed or just a gui mass uninstaller to remove 3rd party packages.

Comment: If you remove the PPA it doesn't remove the package.  You need to use ppa-purge next time, or find the stuff that was installed via PPA and remove them.  There's no mass removal or downgrade tool that confirmed works out of the box.

Comment: this is going be very difficult for me to fix now. Can I restore the missing PPAs or in short the one I deleted?

Comment: Just re-add the PPA.  If you deleted the PPA but don't have it anymore, there's no way to easily 'recover' that data unless you know which PPA you removed.

Comment: That's the problem, I removed like 15-20 PPAs. Everything that was listed under Other Software. Guess I have to reinstall ubuntu only!!

Comment: You can adapt script from https://askubuntu.com/a/6073/66509 or use Aptitude (the *Obsolete and Locally Created Packages* section)  or Synaptic (the *Installed (local or obsolete)* section).